# How can I give dynamic id in jquery with append tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two dynamic values in jQuery. How can I use these value with jQuery append?

```
var pp = $(this).parents().eq(5).attr('id');
var tt = $('#'+pp).find('table').attr('id');
```

Now I want to use it in:

```
var markup='<tr id="record'+n+'" class="form-grid-view-alternate" ><td class="first margin_t8"><input class="set_text_box"  id="span" class="form-label"  type="text" name="record'+n+'"  value="" ></td><td class="second  margin_t8 " style="margin-left:3px !important;margin-right:3px !important;"><span class="list-icon-arrow"><a href="#" class="anchor_style"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up up" aria-hidden="true" ></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down down" aria-hidden="true" ></i></a></span></td><td class="first margin_t8"><input class="set_text_box"  id="span" class="form-label"  type="text" name=""  value="" ></td></tr>';

$("#pp,#tt tbody").append(markup);
```

But it's not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your question needs more detail in order to be answerable. I *assume* that `$("#pp,#tt tbody")` is your attempt at using the `var tt` created in the other snippet, but I don't know (and cannot know).

Comment: You need to add more details like  `HTML` you are having and `markup` variable value too

Comment: include your html markup also.

Comment: updared my markup with the code ..

Comment: Why are you appending the same element to two elements?

Comment: You need to add more HTML like the table HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string `"#pp,#tt tbody"` will not replace `pp` and `tt` with the values of the corresponding variables.

What you should do instead is append `pp` and `tt` to the string passed to JQuery:

```
$("#" + pp + ", #" + tt + " tbody").append(markup);
```

Comment: Ah, I took the selector from the code you provided -- did you mean `$("#pp #tt tbody")` (without the comma)? If so, the code above is the same, but remove the comma and it will only append it to `#tt tbody` once

Comment: hey Christian how to use  var getdata=$('#tt tr:last').attr('id'); with dynamic tt

Comment: Same idea as above, you need to append to the string: `$("#" + tt + " tr:last").attr("id")`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want?

```
$("#" + pp + ",#" + tt + " tbody").append(markup);
```

Comment: harsh@ but in that case my dynamic tr not working correctly